# Inverted index for top tags

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with Spark and I want to know how can I get inverted index for top tags?

```
sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM Users")
sqlDF.show(
```

[image]

```
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+ 
|      id|               title|                tags|closeddate| 
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+ 
|48704243|Transfer files fr...|<java><android><f...| null|
```

Comment: look into `explode` and `split` - you have what you are looking for

Comment: what do you mean by `inverted index for top tags`? do you mean you want the rows with maximum number of tags at the top?

Comment: Yes I want to get output that shows the 5 most popular tags and 5 tags had the most closed issues.